# String variable in java to get and store the json array in table column

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

```
json Array->
 "email_interface":["pch.hiremath@gmail.com","pch.hiremath@gmail.com"],
```

I need to store these emailIds list in a table column how can i do achieve it.

```
@Column(name="email_interface", nullable=true)
    private String email_interface;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize / Deserialize the JSON as String. Use JPA Converters, which shall automatically convert the same.

Suggest to use Jackson JAR for the same.

Comment: @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 @Column(name="protocol", nullable=true)
 private ProtocolTypes protocol;
 
 @Column(name="protocol_interface", nullable=true)
 private Integer protocol_interface;
 
 @Column(name="email_interface", nullable=true)
 private String email_interface;

Comment: if i change to private String[] email_interface its not working

Comment: You could have a look at this page. https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/ for Java ~ DB Converter

Answer (score 0):

The database had support data type (jsonb) for storing this object.
You can reference this.